# Squaring is linear in Galois Field $2$

Tags: coding-theory

In the context of cyclic codes and BCH, consider the generation function of a codeword $c = [c_0 \ldots c_n-1]$ to be $c(x) = c_0 + \cdots + c_{n-1}x^{n-1}$.

Now, in the finite field $F_2[x]$, why is $c(\alpha^2)=c(\alpha)^2, c(\alpha^4)=c(\alpha)^4$ but $c(\alpha^3) \neq c(\alpha)^3$ (with $\alpha$ being primitive element of $F_2[x]/x^3+x+1$)?

I also came across the statement "In fields of characteristic $2$, squaring is a linear function". Why is this true?

Thanks.

Comment: This result is also known as "Freshman's dream" - we have all met calculus students who think it holds in the reals as well. Search this site using that as a buzzword, and you will get a lot of hits. I don't want to single out any of them in particular.

Comment: It is not true that squaring is linear in all fields on characteristic two -- only that it is additive.

Answer (score 0):

because $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2=a^2+b^2$ because the field has characteristic 2.